# PHP Regular Expression get four digits

Tags: php, regex

I have a string: **The_3454_WITH_DAE[2011][RUS][HDVDRip]** and i want to get the four digits of year betwen [] brackets and not 3454 please help me and provide a php example of regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following regex should do the trick

```
$str = 'The_3454_WITH_DAE[2011][RUS][HDVDRip]';
preg_match('/\[([0-9]+)\]/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: this will get any number of digits in square brackets. not just the four the OP is after. not an issue for the example string, but might cause issues on other strings.

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the square brackets in order to match them

```
\[([\d]{4})\]
```

Demo http://codepad.viper-7.com/J4Rnkt

```
preg_match_all(
    '/
        \[           # match any opening square bracket
        ([\d]{4})    # capture the four digits within
        \]           # followed by a closing square bracket
    /x', 
    'The_3454_WITH_DAE[2011][RUS][HDVDRip]',
    $matches
);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [2011]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2011
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/(?<=\[)\d{4}(?=\])/", $subject, $matches);
```

will match four digits if surrounded by square brackets.